# Google Cloud Platform: Is it possible to create project-specific Service Account groups?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In Google Cloud Platform, it seems you can add Service Accounts to Google Groups (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#google_group). However, Google Groups are organization-wide.

Is it possible for a Project Owner (or Editor) to create groups of Service Accounts for use within a single project?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a Google group is organization-wide as you say, however being in a Google group doesn't actually automatically confer any permissions organization-wide. You can create a group and give it permissions on one project only. So one solution is to create a Google group for the project (e.g. project-abc-owners@example.com) and make that group an owner on the project. You can then put service accounts in that group and they will just get access to that project.

Alternatively, you don't have to use groups at all. You can make the service account an owner or editor on the project directly.